# Cannot start spyder3 - ImportError: No module named paths

Tags: python, spyder

I am using the development version of spyder3 ([link](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html)) on Ubuntu 14.04 and I am getting the following error when I run it:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 14, in <module>
    from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
ImportError: No module named paths
```

How do I get past this?

Comment: I solved it using this link: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/270

This means that the IPython being imported is the very-old one installed by apt-get. If you have done pip install --upgrade ipython, that should install a newer IPython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages being on the front of sys.path means that there is an easy-install.pth file with this path, which should be removed. It is caused by a bug in setuptools.

LONG STORY SHORT: (REMOVE THIS FILE) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy-install.pth